# How to bind data to stacklayout in xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I want create vertical ScrollView.
Like this:
[image: vertical]

Here is the code that i tried:

```
<ScrollView x:Name="newArrival" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Always">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Frame BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100">
            <StackLayout>
                <Image HeightRequest="70"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="15" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding Desc}" FontSize="13" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for any helps.

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-forms-3-5-a-little-bindable-love/

Comment: @Jason sorry, i dont really understand.=(

Comment: If you read the blog you will. Anyway your picture is showing a carouselView, this is obviously not a stackLayout case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your Image, you just want to achieve by `ScrollView`, it is not reasonable if you have many Items in this view. I suggest you to achieve that by following three ways.

1. Rotated Xamarin Forms ListView.
2. Custom Control – Grid + Horizontal ScrollView
3. Custom Renders – Android.RecyclerView & iOS.UICollectionView( i recommend it)

If you want to know more details about three ways, you can refer to this link.
https://causerexception.com/2018/02/06/xamarin-forms-ultimate-horizontal-list-guide/

There is code of above demo.

https://github.com/DanielCauser/XamarinHorizontalList

If you have some doubts about databinding of Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) .Please refer to this link.
https://blog.xamarin.com/introduction-to-data-binding/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ScrollView` horizontal and give a `Stacklayout` inside, which is also horizontal oriented. 
In the code-behind you could create your elements dynamically by creating a loop which run through your list with objects you want to bind. 
Whenever a new object comes through the loop, a new element gets created inside the `Stacklayout`.